# how to fetch email , name and image from a result output in different variable

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
 func getFBUserData(){
        if((FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil){
            FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                if (error == nil){
                    //everything works print the user data
                    print(result)                                    
                }
            })
        }
 }
```

Output is:

> Optional({ email = "rajput.abhishek660@gmail.com"; "first_name" = Abhishek; id = 1760800260695143; "last_name" = Rajput; name = "Abhishek Rajput"; picture = { data = { height = 200; "is_silhouette" = 0; url = "platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/…;; width = 200; }; }; })

Comment: Edit your question with that output.

Comment: A tip… this isn't Objective-c, so there's no need to wrap all your `if` conditions in `(brackets)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
if let res = result as? [String:Any] {
       print(res["first_name"])
       print(res["last_name"])
       print(res["name"])
       print(res["email"]) 
       if let picture = res["picture"] as? [String:Any] {                    
           if let data = picture["data"] as? [String:Any] {
                print(data["url"])
           } 
       }
}
```

You can use `Codable` for that also

Comment: Sir how can I store image in  a imgviwer

Comment: if you mean user device then look here https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum-how-to-write-to-the-ios-photo-album , if you want to cache inside app use https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage